# dplyr::recode_factor with a priori unknown levels

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a method to apply dplyr's `recode_factor` when the level that I am wanting to modify is not known beforehand.  For example, I would like to apply `cut(5)` to a column and adjust the first level `(interval)` to start at `0`.

```
set.seed(42)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x <- rgamma(100, 1)
x_cut <- x %>% cut(5)
old_level <- levels(x_cut)[[1]]
new_level <- old_level %>% str_extract_all("[0-9]+\\.([0-9]+)",simplify=TRUE) %>% `[`(2) %>% paste0("(0,",.,"]")
x_cut %>% recode_factor( old_level = new_level) %>% levels
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

I expect to see

```
[1] "(0,1.38]" "(1.38,2.75]"    "(2.75,4.12]"    "(4.12,5.49]"    "(5.49,6.87]"
```

but nothing is changed and I get

```
[1] "(0.00388,1.38]" "(1.38,2.75]"    "(2.75,4.12]"    "(4.12,5.49]"    "(5.49,6.87]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left hand side of your recode pair `old_level = new_level` needs to be evaluated instead of quoted.

Use the `!!` and `:=` syntax to do this:

```
x_cut %>% recode_factor(!!old_level := new_level) %>% levels
```

For example, with `set.seed(42)`:

```
x_cut
#  "(0.00388,1.38]" "(1.38,2.75]" "(2.75,4.12]" "(4.12,5.49]" "(5.49,6.87]"   
old_level
#  "(0.00388,1.38]"
new_level
#  "(0,1.38]"
x_cut %>% recode_factor(!!old_level := new_level) %>% levels
#  "(0,1.38]" "(1.38,2.75]" "(2.75,4.12]" "(4.12,5.49]" "(5.49,6.87]"
```

See the [`dplyr programming docs`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-expressions) for more on `!!` ("bang bang") notation.

Comment: Thanks it appears this works with `recode` but not `recode_factor`.  Perhaps related to this [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3390).

Comment: Hmm...do you mean this solution isn't working?  If so, try updating `dplyr` to development version, this code executes correctly when I run it.